# Como filtrar registros con el mismo numero de teléfono Django

Tags: python, django, orm, filtro

Hola alguien sabe como puedo obtener y contar cuantos registros de personas comparten numero de teléfono?

Por ejemplo

```
Fabian 2314785698

Hernan 4568523157

Vivian 8523578632

Pepito 3001238524
Luissa 3001238524

Camilo 3584569872
Marcos 3584569872
Javier 3584569872

Andres 0312589799
Carlos 0312589799
Sultan 0312589799
```

En total son 8 personas que están compartiendo numero celular en el ejemplo anterior.

```
class PersonaBase(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(maxlength=10)
    telefono = models.CharField(maxlength=10)
```

En mi base de datos son casi 3.000 registros.

No se como seria el filtro teniendo en cuenta lo anterior

```
PersonaBase.objects.filter(telefono=?)
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar

Answer (score 0):

Podrias colocar algo como:

```
from django.db.models import Count    
PersonaBase.objects.filter(telefono="el valor que buscas").annotate(total=Count('nombre'))
```

Comment: Esta opción seria para pasar un solo numero de teléfono, necesito saber el total de personas que comparten el mismo numero de teléfono en un sistema con mas de 3000 registros.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias alternativas, la más simple corresponde a listar todos los números de teléfonos únicos, iterar sobre ellos buscando las personas que lo poseen y contar.

```
telefonos = PersonaBase.objects.all().values_list('telefono', flat=True).distinct()
for telefono in telefonos:
    cantidad_de_repeticiones = PersonaBase.objects.filter(telefono=telefono).count()
    # continua haciendo lo que quieras
```

Esto se puede acelerar haciendo un indice sobre el campo de teléfono, dado que se quieren hacer muchas consultas sobre ese campo.

```
class PersonaBase(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(maxlength=10)
    telefono = models.CharField(maxlength=10, index_db=True)
```

Una solución más eficiente sería convertir el campo de teléfono en un modelo aparte, y referenciarlo por medio de un `ForeignKeyField`

```
class PersonaBase(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(maxlength=10)
    telefono = models.ForeignKeyField(to=Telefono, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Telefono(models.Model);
    numero = models.Charfield(maxlength=10)
```

Esto permitiría poder hacer la siguiente operación, que es mucho mas eficiente:

```
>>> telefonos = Telefono.objects.annotate(num_personas=Count('personaBase'))
>>> telefonos 
<QuerySet [<Telefono: 12345>, <Telefono: 4321>, ...]>
>>> telefonos[0].num_personas
73
```

Además, si tu aplicación tiene muchas repeticiones de números tenerlo como una llave foránea resulta en optimización de almacenamiento.